# Sherlock - Searching inside a "C" Drive for Quest Search?

Tags: sherlock

Is there any logical reason to Search inside a "C" Drive or is just a goof ?

[image]

It definitely blows away the standards of Sherlock built in the previous episodes. Is it just me or anyone else felt the same ?

Comment: Uh, wait, you *did* say a *"big"* goof, did you? I didn't imagine this, did I?

Comment: sherlock and goof not possible :-)

Comment: @NapoleonWilson- I really meant big goof due to the attention-to-detail that he showcased  in the earlier episode. Being a fan of Sherlock, It put me off when observing this in the browser (similar to http://goo.gl/hZ5zuc). If it helps, I'll remove the word "Big" :)

Comment: @Karthik It's just that I had an absolutely hard time imagining anyone noticing that adress line at all, let alone conciously freezing the frame to do so. There's attention to detail and there's things *noone*'s every gonna notice. But of course you can leave that *"big"* in there if it is really that big for you. ;-)

Comment: "in the previous episodes"? This is Season 1 Episode 2. :-)

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I recently started watching this series (just caught up), and I noticed it the first time too. Quite obvious, really. :) Anyway, this is similar to the "goof" where private network IPs are often quoted and used as if they were public IP addresses and only certain "reserved" telephone numbers are mentioned (these may be bought by the production company and used for promotional purposes for the film). Basically, the same reason - to try not to "interfere" too much with the "real world".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That is a local HTML file.
It’s technically possible to include a search form that requests an online search engine. It’s not relevant on which partition this file is saved.

You can try it yourself:

1. Save this as a file named `search.html`:

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <title>Search</title>
   <form action="https://duckduckgo.com/html" method="POST">
     <input type="search" name="q" value="">
     <input type="submit" value="Search">
   </form>
   ```
2. Open the file `search.html` in your browser.
3. Enter something and hit "Search".

You’ll see that this opens the results for your query in an actual Web search engine.

Possible reasons for doing this:

- **Performance** - Loading your local document is faster than loading the real search page
- **Aesthetics** - You might like the design of your own document better
- **Privacy** - It’s conceivable that the search engine uses some undesirable techniques on its homepage (but it’s unlikely that they wouldn’t also use these on the result pages, which you still have to load)
- **Features** - You could provide form elements (like checkboxes) that enable/configure hidden features of the search engine, or which make accessing provided options easier

Comment: +1 for giving an awesome logical hand. I would blindly buy all the above if it wasn't IE !!

Comment: The above html would change the url to duckduckgo.com once you hit "Search". I'm just watching this episode right now, and the url doesn't change. So I'm pretty sure it's just a goof. (Of course you can play with javascript, but let's be honest, why?)